# Syntax for Racket plot

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to follow [the racket documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/plot/intro.html#%28part._.Plotting_2.D_.Graphs%29) on how to use 2D plotting.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to be able to get it to work (probably something simple)

My code is:

```
#lang racket
(require plot)
(plot (function sin (-pi) pi #:label "y = sin(x)"))
```

and the error is:

```
compile: unbound identifier in module in: function
```

I am a racket/lisp newbie, so if it is obvious, I just don't realize it.  I have also tried inserting `(require racket/gui/base)` as well as `(plot-new-window? #t)` but those don't seem to do the trick either.

I'm using racket v5.1.3 on Ubuntu 12.04.  I am not using Dr. Racket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are reading the documentation for 5.3.3, but
has 5.1.3 installed.

In version 5.3.3 the program:

```
#lang racket
(require plot)
(plot (function sin (- pi) pi #:label "y = sin(x)"))
```

works as expected.

Either grab a new version from http://racket-lang.org/download/
or take a look at the old documentation: http://download.racket-lang.org/docs/5.1.3/html/plot/plot.html?q=plot

Comment: aha.  I just assumed the versions wouldn't be so different (but it looks like they are.  Thanks alot!